# Authentication Required when running sample MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis

I am trying to run the following sample projects.

https://github.com/Wintellect/Angular-MVC-Cookbook

There are 3 solutions and I get `Authentication Required` when I run the websites.

All of the solutions have `<authentication mode="None" />` in the `webconfig`.

I am running in VS2012 using the default IIS Express server.

**Can anyone please tell me what I need to do to disable this authentication if it is possible?**

Comment: Quickly looked at the sample project. there is nothing around authentication in there. Have you enabled authentication in IIS? Could you share the IIS settings for your site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the below solution.

Anonymous Authentication in the `Project properties` was set to `disabled`

Project file:

```
<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
```